# Sort 2d array on C

Tags: c++, c

How I can write a program to sort 2D array using C language and without using pointer,
just looping and if statements and using only main function

the array

```
7  5  2
3  1  4
6  9  8
```

and will be

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

please if you can post a sample code :)
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not a 2D array. Also, this kind of "without using, without using..." questions is totally pointless, in my opinion.

Comment: @Daniel, it is when it's formatted correctly :-)

Comment: what it's called ??
Yeah I will not use some thing because that is what I want :)
its a teaching way

Comment: Today, when just about every basic concept in CS can be done for you by some library or your framework, teaching using the "don't use this and that" concept is more relevant then ever. If I'll tell you to perform some complex action, and you return a paper with a single function call that uses some lib in the framework, I'll have done nothing but force you to google a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching the web before posting such questions. Any ways this is a bubble sort implementation in c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 20

void print_array(int *array) {
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
        if(x != ARRAY_SIZE-1)
            fprintf(stdout, "%d, ", array[x]);
        else
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", array[x]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int iarray[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int x, y, holder;

    // Seed rand()
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for(x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++)
        iarray[x] = (int)(rand() % 100);

    fprintf(stdout, "Before Sort\n---------------\n");
    print_array(iarray);  


    // Bubble sort method.
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++)
        for(y = 0; y < ARRAY_SIZE-1; y++)
            if(iarray[y] > iarray[y+1]) {
                holder = iarray[y+1];
                iarray[y+1] = iarray[y];
                iarray[y] = holder;
            }

    fprintf(stdout, "\nAfter Sort\n---------------\n");
    print_array(iarray);  

}
```

Comment: hmmm, I think you don't understand me I am talking about 2D (Matrix) not vector array[3][3] not array[3], how you can help ?

Comment: @user1065588: This is a homework question, and there is more than I would have provided in this answer... you just need to make the loops more complicated to account for the fact that your array is 2D (or ignore it altogether... a 3x3 matrix is an array of 3 arrays and the memory layout will be compatible with an array of 9 elements... but I guess that falls into the *pointers* category)

Comment: Looks to me too as if it is a homework question. As far as the pointer issue is concerned, it could be completely eliminated by using the `iarray` as a global and not passing any value to the function altogether (which is not a good way to write actual programs though). It would require to modify the `print_array` function by replacing each occurence of `array` with `iarray` and removing the parameter to it.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that you need help with the algorithm. For that you can consult http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/65-multidimensional-arrays/

Comment: that page doesn't actually offer a sort for multidimensional arrays

Comment: My friend it actually gives links to the selection sort algorithm. I guess you didn't scroll a bit lower than expected

Comment: It's for a 1d array, but the question asked specifically for a 2d array.